# Como agrego un option value en blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, blade

necesito ayuda para agregar un option value en un view de blade. Actualmente ya tiene uno y quiero agregar otro pero no se donde escribir la variable correspondiente para que lea los datos correctos de la DB
mi codigo actual del view es:

```
@if(count($bloques) > 0)
        <div class="lista-tarjetas__bloques">
            <select wire:model="bloque" wire:change="resetearPagina()" class="tabla__buscador form-control form-control-sm">
                <option value="todos" selected>Todos los bloques</option>
                @foreach ($bloques as $bloque)
                    <option value="{{ $bloque['id'] }}">{{ $bloque['nombre'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="lista-tarjetas__bloques">
            <select wire:model="bloque" wire:change="resetearPagina()" class="tabla__buscador form-control form-control-sm">
                <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
                @foreach ($concejales as $concejal)
                    <option value="{{ $concejal['tipo_autoridad'] }}">{{ $concejal['tipo_autoridad'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: No entiendo, que datos correctos? En lo que muestras veo 2 `option value`. El primero fuera del `foreach` y el otro dentro. En donde quieres agregar tu `option value`?

Comment: El primero es el que funciona, y el segundo el que no logro que funcione